# Conditional Probability Proof for three events

Tags: probability

For any 3 events $X, Y$ and $Z$ where $\Pr Z) > 0$, it is required to prove that
I am not able to prove it.

Comment: You can use the definition of conditional probability, together with set manipulations like $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$.

Comment: How what?  How to use the definition? Just try to use it and see what you get...

Comment: 10 minutes later:  Okay, apparently you haven't tried to do anything.  I am signing off.

Comment: Why don't you try to use the definition of the conditional probability ($P(X\cup Y|Z)= \frac {P(X\cup Y \cap Z)}{P(Z)}$)?

Comment: Conditional probability is a probability _measure_. In simplistic terms, this means that _any_ theorem of (unconditional) probability theory is true if we condition throughout on some event $Z$.  Thus, if $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)\tag{1}$$ is a true statement, then so is  $$P((A\cup B)\mid C) = P(A\mid C) + P(B\mid C) - P((A\cap B)\mid C)\tag{2}$$ a true statement (assuming, of course, that $P(C) > 0$. If you know a proof of $(1)$, you can create from it a proof of $(2)$ by conditioning throughout on event $C$. If you _don't_ know a proof of $(1)$, try proving that before $(2)$.